# What issue will i run into for real time data writing and reading with lots of table using RDS PSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, amazon-rds

I have a solution that writes sensor data to a database every minute but I do not think the way we have our database is scalable. We are using one database and each sensor has its own table. We have around 200,000 sensors (200,000 tables in one database).

RDS database specs:
db.m5.2xlarge
8 CPU
32GB RAM
General Purpose SSD

I was thinking we can do one of these solutions.

1. I was thinking of splitting each the sensors across 4 databases
2. I can create 4 database servers and split them across each database server.

Do you have any suggestion or can you see any issues with these solutions.

Comment: Store the data in a single, perhaps partitioned, table.

Comment: "*can you see any issues with these solutions*" - Yes, likely premature optimization. 200,000 tables sound a little extreme already, and you want to divide it up further into multiple databases and / or servers. You theoretically could house all this data in a single table, such as Laurenz mentions, so long as it's architected properly. Why do you think you need to optimize for performance right now?...what's currently slow?